# how to change LibreOffice UI's language?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I'm using LibreOffice with Ubuntu 16:04. The system is in English. I wanted to change UI only for LibreOffice to Polish.

In LibreOffice in `tools` -> `options` there is only English (and English US) as possible language for UI.

I've checked via terminal, `libreoffice-l10n-pl` and `libreoffice-help-pl` are installed. In `System Tools` - > `Language Settings` Polish is installed.

[image]

Here is an output of `locale` command:

```
maria@maria-Vostro-3360:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Polish ought to be an option for the UI language. I just installed Polish with _Language Support_, and after that I'm able to select Polish in LibreOffice.

Comment: But I have Polish already installed...

Comment: Maybe close LO and open it again...

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I did...

Comment: Can't explain it then.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS just install:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-pl
```

and it will be in Polish.

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu language pack was not installed properly. I installed via Ubuntu settings and then restarted Libreoffice. Now I could see my preferred language as an option.

[screenshot of ubuntu settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5hhA.png)

[screenshot of installed languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv5oC.png)